# will DB Context be automatically disposed if the page is redirected within the using block?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Recently I have discovered one of our web app is spiking CPU and leaking memory, I am trying to find out the cause, below code is similar to the page which has the most loading time, can someone please tell me is there anything wrong with the code, I suspect that dbcontext object is not getting disposed when the if statement matches and redirects to another page.

```
using (databaseEntities dbContext = new databaseEntities())
{
    TABLE1 Existing = dbContext.TABLE1.Where(R => R.IsComplete).FirstOrDefault();
    if (Existing != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SecondView");
    }

    TABLE1 obj = new TABLE1();

    obj.Name = "Name";
    obj.City = "City";
    obj.Date_Created = DateTime.Now;

    dbContext.TABLE1.Add(obj);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Rather than guessing, please *profile* your code to determine what is leaking and where.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for your suggestion, can you please recommend any tools to get me started.

Comment: What is mean this line TABLE1 Existing = dbContext.TABLE1.Where(R => R.IsComplete).FirstOrDefault();

Replace with R=>R.IsCompleted == condition.

Comment: You can use the free version of Stackify Prefix to profile your requests, including the execution time of database queries executed inside each request. It's not a full profiler for your code, but can be very useful to measure at the function block level.

Comment: @AsifRaza - The code provided works fine if the user wants to know the first row where the IsComplete field is true.  `.Where(r=>r.IsComplete)` is equivalent to `.Where(r=>r.IsComplete == true)`.  Conversely, `.Where(r=>!r.IsComplete)` is equivalent to `.Where(r=>r.IsComplete == false)`.  This is not the cause of the OPs compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Your dbContext dispose as soon as the execution leaves the scope. So I don't see any issue with this code.
The using statement compiled to a try-finaly statement which call the dispose method on your object in the finaly block.
For more information, see below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem to be a problem with the DB context as it is getting out of scope just after saving changes. Problem could be with either the Database or the way you have written the constructor for the databaseEntities.
Using will always call finally and scope will end for sure.